# Custom fontweigh otherthan given 9 constants by dart like (550) - Flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, textstyle

I want to use custom fontweight in my text style otherthan flutter given 100, 200 ----- 900  font weights, like Fontweight.w550 or (550 as int).

tried to achieve with this but it doesn't worked out

```
  fontWeight: FontWeight.lerp(FontWeight.w500, FontWeight.w600, 0.5)
```

Your help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

`FontWeight` is a const parameter which is : [w100, w200, w300, w400, w500, w600, w700, w800, w900]

`FontWeight.w500` along with `fontStyle:FontStyle.bold` work in older version, in new version there is nothing which gives `FontWeight 550`.

Comment: as per sky_engine

/// Whether to slant the glyphs in the font
enum FontStyle {
  /// Use the upright glyphs
  normal,

  /// Use glyphs designed for slanting
  italic,
}
we don't have bold